# How do I scrape data through Mechanize and Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I am working on an application which gets the HTML from http://www.screener.in/.

I can enter a company name like "Atul Auto Ltd" and submit it and, from [the next page](http://www.screener.in/company/?q=Atul+Auto+Ltd),
scrape the following details: "CMP/BV" and "CMP".

I am using this code:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

Company_name='Atul Auto Ltd.'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.screener.in/')
form = agent.page.forms[0]
print agent.page.forms[0].fields
agent.page.forms[0]["q"]=Company_name
button = agent.page.forms[0].button_with(:value => "Search Company")
pages=agent.submit(form, button)
puts pages.at('.//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[11]')
# not getting any output.
```

The code is taking me to the right page but I am don't know how to query to get the required data.

I tried different things but was unsuccessful.

If possible, can someone point me towards a nice tutorial which explains how to scrape a particular class from an HTML page. 
The XPath of the first "CMP/BV" is:

```
//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[11]
```

but it is not giving any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) I would go as below:

**Using CSS Selectors**

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.screener.in/company/?q=Atul+Auto+Ltd.'))

doc.class
# => Nokogiri::HTML::Document
doc.css('.table.draggable.table-striped.table-hover tr.strong td').class
# => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

row_data = doc.css('.table.draggable.table-striped.table-hover tr.strong td').map do |tdata|
  tdata.text
end

 #From the webpage I took the below value from the table 
 #*Peer Comparison Top 7 companies in the same business*    

row_data
# => ["6.",
#     "Atul Auto Ltd.",
#     "193.45",
#     "8.36",
#     "216.66",
#     "3.04",
#     "7.56",
#     "81.73",
#     "96.91",
#     "17.24",
#     "2.92"]
```

Looking at the table from the webpage I can see *CMP/BV* and *CMP* are the twelfth and third columns respectively. Now I can get the data from the array `row_data`. So *CMP* is the second index and *CMP/BV* is the last value of the array `row_data`.

```
row_data[2] # => "193.45" #CMP
row_data.last # => "2.92" #CMP/BV
```

**Using XPATH**

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.screener.in/company/?q=Atul+Auto+Ltd.'))

p doc.at_xpath("//*[@id='peers']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]").text
p doc.at_xpath("//*[@id='peers']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[10]").text
# >> "193.45" #CMP
# >> "17.24"  #CMP/BV
```

Comment: It works can u tell me , how you are able to find out css selector? . I traced using chrome Developers tools , so is there any tools for this and how i can do this using xpath.

Comment: I use firefox add-on *Firebug*.

Comment: any idea how to do it with xpath.

Comment: @DeependerSingla Use CSS rules.. its always easy and good to see. :) see my update.

Comment: @okey still there is no harm in trying.

Comment: CSS isn't always the easiest form of a selector but they are usually easier to read. There are times you have to use XPath because it's more full-featured.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes.. you are right.. But if there is a chance to use *CSS Selectors*,I use it there. As it is more readable than `xpath`.

Comment: @Priti Please don't offer the `xpath_for` output as suggested XPath. It tends to produce unreadable expressions because they are a literal translation of the CSS, whereas idiomatic XPath will be shorter and cleaner.

Comment: @priti can you tell me how you got this xpath ? I am using google devlopers tools i am getting this xpath                                       //*[@id="top"]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[10] it is not giving any result and your xpath for same is                                 //*[@id='peers']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[10] .I am a beginner with xpath and CSS if you can help , through what way we can get xpath and CSS path.

Comment: @DeependerSingla I created the `xpath` expression by doing view source on the webpage. Still I would recommend to use CSS Selectors,as you are just started with Nokogiri. Once you willl be familiard with CSS selectors use .. It will slowly help you to buld the `xpath` expression too.. I would like to say you to look into the `Firebug` add-on of Firefox for the same.

Comment: Mechanize includes Nokogiri, so you can load the website with Mechanize agent, then do: Nokogiri::HTML(website.body) to read.  Why use Mechanize? because you can save sessions, avoid robots.txt and some nice things more.