# Problems scraping Google results with Nokogiri and XPATH

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm having issues trying to scrape search results from Google using Nokogiri and XPATH. It's just Google that I'm having issues with, other sites seem to be working fine.

I'm getting an elements XPATH string using Chrome's element inspector.

This is a working Stack Overflow example:

```
# Testing element on StackOverflow - returns the questions text
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763549/how-do-i-scrape-data-through-mechanize-and-nokogiri'))

p doc.at_xpath("//*[@id='question-header']/h1/a").text
=> "How do I scrape data through Mechanize and Nokogiri?"
```

Trying to use Google results in:

```
# Testing element on Google, should return the first result title
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.google.com/#q=stack+overflow+error'))

p doc.at_xpath("//*[@id='rso']/li[1]/div/h3/a").text
NoMethodError: undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
  from (irb):81
  from /home/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
  from /home/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
  from /home/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm getting a "NoMethodError" on all Google pages. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Looks like you're using an asynchronous search that won't be called using `open_uri`. Change your url to `'https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow+error'`.

Comment: I tried not working with thus url too

Comment: I was able to successfully get URL's and titles using Mechanize and Nokogiri.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not return the data you're looking for in the response. This element is fetched with JavaScript when the page loaded by the browser. Nokogiri does not run any JavaScript on a page.

Comment: What's the alternative for scraping Google search results?

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger `watir` or `selenium-webdriver`.

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger I believe scraping is against the TOS. There is an API, however.

Comment: Google sheets is the alternative. I have entire pages/softwares essentially that I built for my own workflows to get the results I need when needed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem that might cause the error is that you don't specify a `user-agent`, thus Google blocks your request.

For example in Python [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#quickstart), the default `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) which needs to be changed, otherwise, it might block the request because it's a bot.

Also, [Zach Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025844/problems-scraping-google-results-with-nokogiri-and-xpath#comment33390625_22025844) pointed that the URL is a bit wrong, e.g `#q=` should be `?q=`

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'

headers = {
  "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  q: "stackoverflow error",
  hl: "en"
}

response = HTTParty.get('https://www.google.com/search',
                        query: params,
                        headers: headers)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)

puts doc.at_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "yuRUbf")]/a/h3/text()')

# or at_css which is faster for class names and produces better XPath
puts puts doc.at_css(".yuRUbf/a/h3/text()")

---
#=> What is a StackOverflowError? - Stack Overflow
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that all that needs to be done is just to iterate over structured `json` string rather than figuring out stuff. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

```rb
require 'google_search_results' 

params = {
  api_key: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  engine: "google",
  q: "stackoverflow error",
  hl: "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch.new(params)
hash_results = search.get_hash

# [0] first element from organic results
puts hash_results[:organic_results][0][:title]

---
#=> StackOverflowError (Java Platform SE 7 ) - Oracle Help Center
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.